# Multiple canvas connections in the same figure

Tags: canvas, matplotlib, event-handling

I have one figure with 3 axes. I connect with `mpl_connect` to the 2 of them by `'pick_event'` which plots something on the 3rd axis. Example (I omit the irrelevant variables and some parts of the code to make it more clear and simple):

```
class ManualElimination:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig=figure()
        self.cid2=None
        self.cid1=None
        self.data1=None
        self.data2=None
        nrows=2
        ncols=4
        self.ax1=plt.subplot2grid((nrows, ncols), (0, 0), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
        self.ax2=plt.subplot2grid((nrows, ncols), (0, 1), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
        self.ax4=plt.subplot2grid((nrows, ncols), (1, 0), colspan=ncols-1, rowspan=1)
        self._replot()
    def _onpick_plot_2(self, event):
        try:
            self.x=self.cat[self.keys[self.ind]].members[int(self.data2[event.ind[0],-1])]
            self.pickedid=self.x.id
            self._replot()
            self._onpick_plot_flux()
        except:
            self.x=None
            self.pickedid=None
            self._replot()
            pass
    def _onpick_plot_1(self, event):
        try:
            self.x=self.cat[self.keys[self.ind]].members[int(self.data1[event.ind[0],-1])]
            self.pickedid=self.x.id
            self._replot() # I need this to plot the selected point in different color; this is not included in this code example to make it more simple
            self._onpick_plot_flux()
        except:
            self.x=None
            self.pickedid=None
            self._replot()
            pass
    def _onpick_plot_flux(self):
        x=self.x
        self.ax4.cla()
        sp = np.loadtxt(filename)
        self.ax4.plot(sp[:,0], sp[:,1])
        show()

    def _replot(self):
        self._clear_axes() # not defined in this example; clears all 4 axes
        self._get_data_all() # not defined here, affects self.data1 and self.data2

        if self.data1 is not None:
            self.line=self.ax1.scatter(self.data1[:,2], self.data1[:,0], picker=5)
            self.cid1=self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self._onpick_plot_1)

        if self.data2 is not None:
            self.line=self.ax2.scatter(self.data2[:,2], self.data2[:,0], picker=5)
            self.cid2=self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self._onpick_plot_2)

        self.fig.canvas.show()
```

When I pick a point on one of the axes (`ax1` or `ax2`), it seems that a random function (`self._onpick_plot_1` or `self._onpick_plot_2`) is called. Connections have different ids (`self.cid1!=self.cid2`). How to call the right function corresponding to the axis where the point was picked?

Comment: Problem solved: I use `axes_enter_event` first to detect on each axis I am and then connect with the `pick_event` where I pass the corresponding function as an argument. Example: `if event.inaxes==self.ax1: self.fig.mpl_connect('pick_event', self._onpick_plot_1)`.

Comment: Please answer your own question as an answer (and accept it when the system will let you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the `axes_enter_event` first to detect on each axis I am and then connect with the `pick_event` where I pass the corresponding function as an argument. Example: `if event.inaxes==self.ax1: self.fig.mpl_connect('pick_event', self._onpick_plot_1)`.